# Is it possible to use the latest MUI datepickers when using Material-UI 4.9.10?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import React from 'react';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { DateTimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker';


export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
    dayjs('2014-08-18T21:11:54'),
  );

  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <Stack spacing={3}>
        <DateTimePicker
          label="Date&Time picker"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
      </Stack>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

I tried to use this snippet from the docs. I modified a little bit and put it into a sandbox and it seems it's not rendering because of a lot of unidentified errors in the logs. Is there any way to make it work?

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-paper-forked-1ndr6p?file=/src/App.js

I am trying to find a quick solution for this.

Comment: `@mu/x-date-pickers` has `@mui/material` (MUI 5) 5.2.3+ as a peer dependency in it's [initial check in](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/0b46ebc7f9557a9d73b6b7fae5ea3a0b8741d011/packages/x-date-pickers/package.json), meaning it never supported `@material-ui/core` (MUI 4). If you want date pickers for MUI 4 you will have to use the older library `@material-ui/pickers`.

Comment: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datetime-picker this? are there other libraries?

Comment: Is there a tool to rapidly check if a library is compatible, and are there ways to make them compatible even when they're not?

Comment: That is the older library for date pickers. There is no rapid way to check that I know, each package pulled from NPM will include a package.json file that will specify dependencies and peer dependencies. Dependencies will be automatically acquired and peer dependencies are up to the user to include. It can be assumed that if a package lists another package as a dependency that it needs the functionality provided by that package.

Comment: Nothing is impossible though and if you truly hate your life you could make your bundler resolve  `@mui/material` and the other MUI 5 packages to something else. You will however find yourself in a giant blackhole of time wastage as you try and fulfil all the functionality that those packages were providing. You would be better off using the older MUI 4 date picker library or updating your solution to MUI 5.